# MySQL Record Locking Philosophy

Tags: mysql, record-locking

not entirely a technical question, more a procedural one.

How do you go about Record Locking?

If I take a simple Address Application as example, user 1 selects a record with the intention to update. He gets to the Data entry screen and Boom, it is Lunch time.
User 2 goes to Lunch later and wants to update the same Address. Doesn't get a record lock error as this has already timed out.
User 1 comes back from Lunch and still has the old data on the screen. Makes his changes and clicks update, potentially overwriting changes done by user 2 in his absence.

How do you guys handle such situation?

Suggestion for Process Flow

Comment: The screen should read the last modified time when it renders. When the screen tries to save, it should check the modified time, and if it is different, the update fails.

Comment: You can check the mtime using a separate query, but if you want to avoid race conditions, consider doing `UPDATE address SET a = 'x', c = 'y', .... WHERE id = 1 AND mtime = '2024-03-03 03:03:03`. If there are zero updates from the update then the mtime had changed, and an error should be shown.

Comment: But how do you want to do that? You would need to check that the LOCK has expired. In essence, you might as well develop your own LOCKING system, if you already update LAST MODIFIED. I know what you are saying, but that is not working within the System. It is building bridges. Our Posts got out of sequence. I know the technical aspect, but again, then I am more or less doing it outside of the DB Engine.

Comment: Yes, you need your own locking system. Database-level locks are for instantaneous situations to prevent race conditions, and not for cases where a record editor goes to lunch, leaving a record locked. MySQL does not have any mechanism to lock records in that fashion (and neither does any modern RDBMS, as far as I know).

Comment: Thanks. Appears to be a Client/Server issue. That was never a problem in the good old Mainframe times when basically a Session was doing the Looking. For as long as the User was signed on, no Problem. Ok. I take your suggestion and do my own thing. Not very convinient, but there doesn't seem to be an elegant Solution.

Comment: No problem. It is not a lot of code, and if you have many screens that would need to lock records from different tables, you could develop a generalised locking solution that you implement in your web/desktop application framework. Then you can deploy a new locking solution fairly easily when a new screen is added.

Comment: Another thing you could do is where a screen is left open but the lock is about to expire, pop up a message to ask the user if they still want to edit, and if they don't answer within a timer limit, it reverts them to the list view for that table, losing any changes they have made (but not committed).

Comment: Yeah, there is some caveat whatever you (I) do. Instead of a time stamp compare, might as well have my own TABLE which does the same and no change to existing Tables. Drawback is obviously that records might not get released. In addition, I am thinking about doing all the SQL stuff through AJAX instead of FORM POSTS. I need to think about that for a while. The time stamp has it's plusses, because it would be "self healing", if you will. The AJAX could be an "easier" way to show before and after records (if needed). As I said, thinking is required. There is also the REDIRECT issue to be sorted.

Comment: With JAVASCRIPT I can use location.reload(), which would "repost". Depending on Page design, it would re-read the same page, but retrieve the altered MySQL record.

Comment: Yes, if the record had been modified by another user, then it generally should show the latest records. If you were to refresh the detail review rather than a general list view, then you could detect the changed mtime, and alert the user to the fact that the record had been modified.

Comment: Depends on sequence. I could detect the change before the update attempt, issue a message to that effect, show Data differences where possible and do the RELOAD to the detail review screen. That's not much of a problem, if I stay on the same page vs. doing a FORM POST and need to figure out the Parent from the history and even that might not work as my POST data gets lost. I don't have that problem with a RELOAD. But again, there might be some consequences I am not yet aware of.